# Excluding certain fields from an SQL SUM query

Tags: sql, mysql

I am using the following SUM query with SQL

```
SELECT SUM(cost) as total FROM sales where passport =
```

How would I exclude certain records from the calculation, for example where paid = 1?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this ?

```
SELECT SUM(cost) as total FROM sales where (passport = $myPassport AND paid <> 1)
```

Comment: Yes yes, already corrected it...

Gimme a chance instead of downvoting me :( 

:)

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
SELECT SUM(cost) as total 
FROM sales
WHERE passport = ?
 AND paid <> 1
```

You may also be looking for a group by here

```
SELECT passport, SUM(cost) as total 
FROM sales
WHERE passport = ?
 AND paid <> 1
GROUP BY passport
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(cost) as total FROM sales where passport = "12345" and paid <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(cost) as total 
FROM sales 
WHERE passport = 12345
AND paid <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

did you mean to get only total that equal to  1 ?

USE : `HAVING total = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's useful to use IF statements like that:

```
SELECT COUNT(mct.id), SUM(mct.cost * IF(mct.status = 1, 0, 1))
FROM my_cool_table mct;
```

In that way when status field equals 1 cost will be multiplied by 0 and excluded from SUM but row will not be excluded for count function.

Another way is to use select inside SUM, but it will be not so useful.