# Doing an SQL query in PHP where a field from a different table is referenced

Tags: php, sql, mysql

OK,

In this query I am displaying the sales for a particular person, matching the passport number from the current form I am working on.

What I want to do however, is to sum the total sales and display it, excluding records which have been marked as paid.

I am having trouble because "paid" does not existent in the current form I am working on as a variable, nor the table it relates to.

I can´t use row['paid'] as I need to do this query outside of the while loop.

What should I do in this situation?

```
$sqlstr = mysql_query(
        "SELECT * FROM sales where passport = ".
        "'{$therecord['passport']}'");
if (mysql_numrows($sqlstr) != 0) {
    echo "<b>Sales for {$therecord['firstname']} ".
            "{$therecord['lastname']}</b><br />";
    echo "<table><tr>";
    echo '<tr><th align="left">Name</th><th align="left">Quantity</th>".
            "<th align="left">Cost</th></tr>';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlstr)) {
        echo "<td>{$row['product']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row['quantity']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row['cost']}</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}

echo "</table>";
$sqltotal = mysql_query(
        "SELECT SUM(cost) as total FROM sales where passport = ".
        "'{$therecord['passport']} AND {$therecord['paid']} <> 1'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sqltotal);
echo "<br /><b>Total Owing: {$row['total']}</b>";
```

Comment: You really should start indenting your code.

Comment: While on the subject of coding style, your variable name `$therecord` is unnecessarily verbose. Why not just call it `$record`? And is `$therecord` from a table called `records`? If not, the name is ambiguous ("record" is often synonymous with "row" or "result"). It would be better to avoid such variable names and instead use names like `$sale`, `$user`, `$product`, etc.

Comment: I  think we need to see how you generated $therecord, also your $sqltotal query doesn't make any sense, {$therecord['paid']} <> 1

Comment: I can´t show where $therecord is generated, as it is done automatically by the CMS system I am working with. My sql query is based on an aswer to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184872/excluding-certain-fields-from-an-sql-sum-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've misplaced simple quote in :

```
"'{$therecord['passport']} AND {$therecord['paid']} <> 1'"
```

it must be :

```
"'{$therecord['passport']}' AND {$therecord['paid']} <> 1"
```

Comment: Hmm, I still get an error Undefined index: paid when trying that solution.

Comment: what's the contents of $therecord['paid'] ?

Comment: I can´t even access it, as it gives the undefined index error. That is kind of my problem, $therecord has just results from a table which does not have a paid field. So I need to access it in the query I make from the sales table in my query above.

Comment: May be your field is paid instead of $therecord['paid'] so you'll have :"'{$therecord['passport']}' AND paid <> 1"

Comment: Hmm, that seems to be it, except now nothing is output for the total at all.

Comment: Are you sure that you have data in your DB. Try SELECT cost FROM ... instead of SELECT SUM(cost) ...

Comment: Definitly data in the DB...the individual sales and costs are showing, just not the totals.

Answer (score 1):

You could either create a MySQL view, of look at SQL joins. I'm not sure on your database structure, but you should have a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT SUM(sales.cost) AS total
FROM sales, table2
WHERE sales.passport = '$passport_id'
AND sales.passport = table2.passport
AND table2.paid = '1'
```

Not sure as that was wrote off-hand. Again, it'd be better if we knew the structure of your tables.