# Summing a field while excluding certain fields in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, null

I am trying to suma column in a table, while excluding certain records that have the paid field set to true.

I am doing so like this:

```
SELECT SUM( cost ) AS total
FROM sales
WHERE passport = 'xxxxx'
AND paid <>1
```

The table is full of data, and I can display costs by themselves, or the entire total. Just adding on 
    AND paid <>1
Is what causes it to fail. The query does not fail as such, but NULL is returned which is quite useless.

This is the SQL for my table

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  uuid varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  firstname varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  lastname varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  passport varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  product varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  quantity int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  cost double DEFAULT NULL,
  paymenttype varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  paid tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  tabno varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  createdby int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  creationdate datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  modifiedby int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  modifieddate timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

And the current data

```
INSERT INTO sales (id, uuid, firstname, lastname, passport, product, quantity, cost, paymenttype, paid, tabno, createdby, creationdate, modifiedby, modifieddate) VALUES
(20, ':8dcee958-d1ac-6791-6253-0a7344054295', 'Jason', 'Hoff', 'r454545', 'Nicaraguan nachoes', 4, 320, 'credit', 1, '23434', 2, '2010-07-06 04:10:18', 2, '2010-07-06 04:10:18'),
(19, ':3f03cda5-21bf-9d8c-5eaa-664eb2d4f5a6', 'Jason', 'Hoff', 'r454545', 'Nica Libre (doble 4 o 5 anos)', 1, 30, 'cash', NULL, '35', 2, '2010-07-06 03:35:35', 2, '2010-07-06 03:35:35'),
(18, ':f83da33b-2238-94b9-897c-debed0c3815e', 'Jason', 'Hoff', 'r454545', 'Helado con salsa de chocolate', 1, 40, 'cash', 1, '2', 2, '2010-07-05 21:30:58', 2, '2010-07-05 21:30:58');
```

Comment: Are you sure there are records matching `WHERE passport = 'xxxxx' AND paid <>1`

Comment: I have 3 records, the passport number is the same for all of them, and paid is set for only 2 of them.

Comment: You have already asked [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184872/excluding-certain-fields-from-an-sql-sum-query) and accepted the answer. You should edit that question as appropriate, rather than starting a new one.

Comment: @Mike, since I already answered it (prematurely), then surely editing it would not be fair?

Comment: @Jacob: You can always change the answer that you accepted. It may help others who are searching for something similar. As for whether it's fair or not, I'll leave that for others to decide ;-) From the [SO FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq): *Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question.*

Comment: @Mike, what would then happen to this question and the answers? - At the moment this seems like the more comprehensive question and answers...would it maybe make more sense to remove the original I asked?

Comment: @Jacob: Fair point - it might not be worth changing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM( cost ) AS total
FROM sales
WHERE passport = 'xxxxx'
AND paid = false or paid is null
```

EDITED

use

```
IS NOT
```

instead of

```
!=
```

This should work

```
SELECT SUM( cost ) AS total
FROM sales
WHERE passport = 'xxxxx'
AND paid IS NOT true
```

Comment: Hmm, this still returns NULL. I have edited my question to show the contents of the table.

Comment: @Jacob:- because in all your data paid is set to TRUE

Comment: Salil, the middle record has paid set to NULL.

Comment: @jacob:- check my EDITED answer i hope that helps :)

Answer (score 2):

The 'paid' value is NULL for that row. You would need to do

```
SELECT SUM( cost ) AS total
FROM test.sales
WHERE passport = 'r454545'
AND paid IS NULL or paid = 0 
     /*Or paid <> 1 as I see you are using tinyint datatype*/
```

Or, better would be to not allow NULLS in that column and have paid default to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your condition does not match any rows.

The condition `paid <> 1` does not match the row where `paid` is `NULL`.

Try this query: `SELECT 1 <> NULL` It will return `NULL`. A `WHERE` clause filters out rows in which the clause is either false or `NULL`.

Replace `AND paid <> 1` with `AND (paid IS NULL OR paid <> 1)`

Answer (score 1):

The book [SQL Antipatterns](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) describes this problem in detail, section *Searching Nullable Columns*. Strongly recommended book.

Answer (score 0):

This may mean there are no rows in the table for which paid <> 1. Or maybe there are but they cost of NULL.

Comment: no costs are null, and there are records where paid is not set to one.

Comment: You don't have a passport of 'xxxxx'. Presumably that wasn't the real value? Also, you have a NULL in the paid column. That might lead to trouble if you plan to use it as a boolean type.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use "<>", but use "!=" instead;

```
SELECT SUM( cost ) AS total
FROM sales
WHERE passport = 'xxxxx'
AND paid != 1
```

If that doesn't work, can you post the table definition? And are there any records which do not have paid = 1?

Comment: yes, there is one record where paid is not set to one. Using the above, only NULL is still returned.

Comment: `<>` is standard SQL. `!=` is supported by some, but by no means all, databases, and is not standard.